# How to vertically align label and span when the span is inline-block?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically align `label` and `span` elements by using `align-middle` but it's not working:

```css
.circle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="align-middle">
        <label><span class="circle" style="background-color:blue;"></span>Text</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, perhaps in this case it's better to use other elements than `label` and `span`?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .circle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
</style>


<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="align-middle">
    <label>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color:blue;"></span>
        Text
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using vertical-align can help you align items on the same line. Also, you could play with line-height to have them perfectly aligned. Now it works easily since your line-height is 24px, almost the same as your circle.

Comment: thanks! although in my code it does not work, yet here it does, any idea what could cause that? computed properties seem correct

Comment: This certainly has something to do with parent elements that you did not include in your question. Try to provide more code, while still keeping it to the minimum necessary to reproduce the error.